# I need to create a kafka image with topics already created from docker compose

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I'm working with the jhipster kafka implementation, that uses the confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.4.0 image, when I try to create the Kafka topics using the environment variable "KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS:", I don't get any error but the topics are not being created, I'm thinking of three different ways to attack the problem,

1. creating the topics by command on the docker-compose file.
2. change the image of Kafka and zookeeper to another one like wurstmeister image.
3. create the topics manually on the docker container and then commit the changes creating my own image of Kafka with the topics already created.

which options does sound better, or has someone created the topics successfully using the environment variable on the confluentinc image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered, that variable only exists on wurstmeister images.

In fact, there's noting stopping you from using the wurstmeister images and something else for Zookeeper and other containers in your compose file. *Its all the same **Apache Kafka***.

Personally, I would programmatically craete the topics in code. In Spring-Kafka, this can be done with beans.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#configuring-topics

Answer (score 0):

`KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS` is specific to the wurstmeister image.

I'm only familiar with the Confluent docker images. I would use your first suggestion, creating the topics by command on the docker-compose file.